# Refer to method in a constructor (java)

Tags: java, methods, constructor

```
class A {

    private List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
    private B example;

    public A(List<B> list) {
        this.list = list; 
        this.example = setExample();
    }

    private B setExample() {
        B object;
        //do something with the list
        return object;
    }

}
```

Would something like this be possible? The object has a list, but I want a specific element of that list to also be stored in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is fine as long as the method is not overridable. Overridable methods must not be called in constructors.

Therefore if this class is designed to be inherited from, the setExample() method should be made final if it was public or protected but it is private so that is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks! this saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works fine, but you don't need to initialize your variable `list` with an empty list, because you assign the passed list to it in the constructor, effectively throwing the new list away again.

Comment: You are right, I don't know why I added that here. Thank you.